# What is reaction attack?

Tags: public-key, terminology, side-channel-attack

In the paper of **"*Reaction Attacks against Several Public-Key Cryptosystems*"** [CiteSeerX link](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.91.8267), reaction attack is defined informally as **"Obtaining information about the private key or plaintext by watching the reaction of someone decrypting a given ciphertext with the private key."**

Is reaction attack explicitly defined in literature? What is the difference between fault attack and reaction attack -as defined here- ?

Comment: Reading their abstract, I'm certain it's an umbrella term for side-channel attack (and you've tagged as such).

Comment: Paper is [here](https://cypherpunks.ca/~iang/pubs/paper-reaction-attacks.pdf) it is well-written about it on the second page. Yes, it is a side-channel but not a fault attack that targets the hardware, this is a soft attack that you get only information from the reaction like the CBC-padding oracles or the tag mismatch in GCM...

Comment: Are decryption failure attacks in these class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Reaction attack" seems to be just a custom name used in a few papers, meaning the reaction of the decryption oracle on maliciously crafted/modified ciphertexts. These are just CCA attacks, not side-channel attacks a priori, but in some cases side channel information such as timing can be used.

These attacks are based exploiting the decryption oracle. Note that many CPA-secure schemes are not CCA-secure (e.g. CBC encryption of a block cipher is vulnerable to the padding oracle attack), however there are ways to convert them in CCA-secure schemes (e.g. adding a MAC for symmetric encryption, or the Fujisaki-Okamoto (FO) transformation for asymmetric schemes).

Comment: An example of "reaction" would be an error code that differs according to what went wrong in a decryption operation. I would rather take a position about the most natural endianness than about if that varying error code qualifies as a side-channel.